# Issue in sending email with SMTP and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, smtp

I am using CI for a quiz system. But during sending mail through SMTP. I am getting this error

following SMTP error was encountered: 111 Connection refused
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

What may be possible reasons of this error.

Configurations used

```
SMTP
Smtp.gmail.com
467
Gmail username
Gmail password
Mail type text
```

Comment: The error is vague at best, but considering most instances now use TLS 1.2, have you checked your SSL configuration?

Comment: is this sorted ?